# Apps Script Add-on Card Service Refresh Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-workspace-add-ons

I created add-ons with the card service.
All I wanted is to run the function `refresh()` to clear data in Spreadsheet and add-on should refresh once I press Logout Button.

I use the below code to try running the function `refresh()` and my Add-ons should reload to display some details. Redirect URL (`cardFooter1Button1OpenLink1`) is working fine, but it's not calling the function `refresh`

```
function refresh(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var clear = sheet.getSheetByName('OfficeUsers'); 
var range = clear.getRange('D3:I').clearContent()
}


function newdemo(){
 var cardFooter1Button1Action1 = CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('refresh');

    var cardFooter1Button1OpenLink1 = CardService.newOpenLink()
        .setUrl('www.office.com/logout')
        .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON);

    var cardFooter1Button1 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Logout')
        .setOnClickAction(cardFooter1Button1Action1)
        .setOpenLink(cardFooter1Button1OpenLink1);

    var cardFooter1 = CardService.newFixedFooter()
        .setPrimaryButton(cardFooter1Button1);

    var cardSection1 = CardService.newCardSection();


    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setFixedFooter(cardFooter1)
        .addSection(cardSection1)
        .build();
  return card;

}
```

Please help me, When I press Logout, It's redirecting to URL and when I close the pop up, it's refreshing the add-on also as I expected but function `refresh()` is not calling.

Comment: Can you please include a minimal example that reproduces the issue? A copy of the spreadsheet that you're working with would be helpful. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.